# Getting QgsMapCanvas viewport's four corners' coordinates

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgsmapcanvas

I have a PyQGIS application that uses the `QgsMapCanvas` as map display. I am trying to retrieve its four corners' coordinates, but couldn't find any public function to do that. All I have is its `width()` and `height()`.

Is there any way to get the actual coordinates of the corners of the viewport?

Let me provide further context, I need the map canvas's viewport's corners' coordinates when it has not had any layers loaded into it yet or the first layer I am constructing is in memory that has yet to set its projection, I found that in such cases, the map canvas's extent is empty, so calling its extent won't help.

Answer (score 3):

Would `extent()` work?

```
canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
extent = canvas.extent()
print(extent)
```

Taking it one step further you can break the `QgsRectangle` object into its components:

```
xmax = extent.xMaximum()
ymax = extent.yMaximum()
xmin = extent.xMinimum()
ymin = extent.yMinimum()
```

Comment: No, when there is no data layer added to the canvas, or dynamically adding features into a "in memory" layer on an empty canvas, the extent is empty, so calling extent would not work.

Comment: @ForComment - The extent returned here is for the [map canvas](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsMapCanvas.html#af903acccfb6e0390af022ac1fbf7b466), not of any layer.

Comment: Yes, I want the map canvas's current viewport's corners' coordinates, but if you try it either in QGIS python console or in a standalone PyQgis app, you will find that there seems to be no way of getting them directly. I like to be told that I am wrong.

Comment: I have a blank canvas and it was able to calculate the extents using the python console.`canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
extent = canvas.extent()
print(extent)
<QgsRectangle: -2.02627511591962906 -1, 2.02627511591962906 1>
xmax = extent.xMaximum()
ymax = extent.yMaximum()
print(xmax)
2.026275115919629
print(ymax)
1.0`

Answer (score 0):

`QgsMapCanvas` is just a subclass of the Graphics View Framework's `QGraphicsView` class.  The documentation for `QgsMapCanvas` doesn't list the base class members, so you need to consult the Graphics View Framework documentation.

For example: https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt4/qgraphicsview.html

The `sceneRect()` method is probably what you want.  It gives you the rectangle of the `QGraphicsView` (or `QgsMapCanvas`) object, relative to the underlying `QGraphicsScene`.  The rectangle is returned as a `QRectF` object.

So, if `myMapCanvas` holds your `QgsMapCanvas` object ...

```
 myCanvasRect = myMapCanvas.sceneRect()
```

`QRectF` has methods like `x()`, `y()`, `width()`, `height()`, `left()`, `right()`, `top()` and `bottom()` that return float values.

It also has convenience methods, like `center()`, `topLeft()`, `bottomRight()` etc. that return `QPointF` objects.

Don't confuse the `sceneRect()` and `extent()` methods.  The former returns a rectangle in scene space.  The latter returns a rectangle in map space.